# How to add an object to model during UnitTest in Spring

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, mocking, spring-test

My code:

```
@Controller 
public class Controller {
   @Autowired
   Service service;

   @RequestMapping(value = "/")
   public ModelAndView showPage() {
      ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
      Object object = service.findObject();
      modelAndView.addObject("modelObject", object);
      m.setViewName("page")
      return modelAndView;
}

@Service
public class Service {
   public Object findObject() {
      // goes to database and finds object
      return object;
}
```

I want to test *in isolation* the controller (i.e. a UnitTest on the controller). 
This is a snippet of my test:

```
@Mock
Service serviceMock;

@InjectMocks
Controller controller;

@Test
when(serviceMock.findObject()).thenReturn(new Object());

mockMvc.perform(get("/")).
   andExpect(model().attribute("modelObject", hasSize(1)));
```

So here the problem: the "expect" of the test fails, because the model is empty. In fact the service is mocked (and this is what I want, in fact I want to test the controller in isolation), so it doesn't go in the database and doesn't find the object.
How can I test this? How can I simulate the fact that the object should be added to the model?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the stupid simple way, with Moktio (or some other Mocking Framework) but without Spring.

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
...


@Test
public void test(){
    Service serviceMock = mock(Service.class)
    when(serviceMock findObject()).thenReturn(new Object());

    Controller controller new Controller();
    controller.setService(serviceMock);

    ModelAndView result = controller.showPage();
    assertThat(model().attribute("modelObject"), hasSize(1));
}
```

Comment: showPage() is controller.showPage() ? By the way, without spring is a mess (I reported a simplified case of my problem)...but why your solution should be different? When you call showPage(), the method findObject is mocked anyway

Comment: @PenguinEngineer: "showPage() is controller.showPage()" - yes, I fixed it. "but why your solution should be different" - just because it works because my solution invoke the mocked controller, but your code invoke the not mocked controller. "By the way, without spring is a mess" - yes it is, but this is allways the problem when you use mocks. So try to reduce the amout of tests that need this kind of mocks.

Comment: I didn't understand why your solution invoke the mocked controller. You wrote Controller controller = new Controller(), there is no mocking here

Comment: @PenguinEngineer: because of the line below: `controller.setService(mockedService);`

Comment: I'm not agree with you, sorry. First of all, I want to test the controller, so I don't  want to mock it: I want to mock the service (that is a dependency for the controller) but I want to test the real controller.
Furthermore, in your code you instantiate an object of type Controller, so the real Object, and not the mocked one.

Comment: @PenguinEngineer: You misunderstood the term "mocked controller" (vs mock): a "mocked" something this is the right/original something but it is "mocked" because its references are mocks. So my code create a Service Mock and use it *to* mock the controller

Comment: Ok, so also my solution uses a "mocked controller", because I inject the service (the Mock) using @InjectMocks. I don't see the difference between the two solutions

Comment: The key difference is, that I invoke the controller directly, but you try to use spring to invoke them, and spring invoke the normal instance but not the mocked one that is created in the test,